# Conectarme a sql server de una conexión remota

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero conectarme a una database de una conexión de escritorio remoto, pero al momento de poner el server en el sql para conectarme me aparece un error:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to servername
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-53-database-engine-error
>
> ---
>
> No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de la red

No se si tenga que hacer otra configuración aparte para poder conectarme.

Comment: Ya verificaste que tengas conexión al servidor y que tengas acceso al puerto en el firewall?

Comment: Sí, aun con la conexión abierta no me deja

Comment: Ese error es por conectividad de red. Es meramente configuración.

Comment: Sería ya problema del sql server que tengo en la conexión remota?